# Convergence of moments of binomial to Poisson

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, convergence, moments

As is well known, the $\mathsf{Binomial}(n,p)$ *distribution* converges to the $\mathsf{Poisson}(a)$ distribution as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $p\rightarrow 0$ with $np=a$.

I'm pretty sure that the *moments* of $\mathsf{Binomial}(n,p)$ also converge to those of $\mathsf{Poisson}(a)$, but I don't know how to prove it. Convergence in distribution doesn't imply convergence of moments, in general. **How can I prove that the moments converge?**

I've found that the binomial *probability (mass) function* converges *uniformly* to the Poisson one. This is stronger than convergence in distribution, so perhaps it can be exploited (but if so I don't know how).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the characteristic function (cf) of a Bernoulli$(p)$ variate is

$$\psi_p(t) = 1 + p(e^{it}-1),$$

the [cf of a sum of $n$ independent such variates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) (which is a Binomial$(p,n)$ variable) is

$$\psi_p(t)^n = \left(1 + p(e^{it}-1)\right)^n = \left(1 + \frac{np(e^{it}-1)}{n}\right)^n.$$

It is well known (and easy to show, even for Complex numbers) that

$$\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$

converges to $\exp(x)$ as $n\to \infty$.  Keeping $np=a$ constant as $n$ increases allows us to write

$$x = np(e^{it}-1) = a(e^{it}-1).$$

Therefore

$$\psi_p(t)^n \to \exp(x) = \exp(a(e^{it}-1)).$$

Because this is the [characteristic function of a Poisson$(a)$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), and all the characteristic functions we have considered are analytic in a neighborhood of $t=0$ with power series whose coefficients give the moments, the moments of the Binomial distributions must have converged to the moments of this Poisson distribution, *QED*.

Comment: Thanks! This the type of general method I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I think I found an answer using [factorial moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_moment). *Still, I will accept someone else's answer if they can shed some light into the more general case, such as giving sufficient conditions that assure convergence*.

The $r$-th factorial moment of the binomial distribution is easily computed as
$$
\mathrm E[(X)_r] = (n)_r\, p^r,
$$
where $(a)_r = a(a-1)\cdots(a-r+1)$ denotes the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol); and that of the Poisson distribution is
$$
\mathrm E[(X)_r] = a^r.
$$
It is clear that $(n)_r\, p^r$ tends to $a^r$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $p \rightarrow 0$ with $np=a$. Thus the binomial factorial moments converge to the Poisson ones.

The $r$-th moment is a linear combination of the $0$-th, ..., $r$-th factorial moments:
$$
\mathrm E[X^r] = \sum_{k=0}^r \left\lbrace\ r\atop k \right\rbrace \mathrm E[(X)_j],
$$
where $\left\lbrace\ r\atop k \right\rbrace$ denotes the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). This expression, together with the convergence of the factorial moments, implies the convergence of the moments.

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be an overkill to this particular problem, but the idea of exploiting uniform integrability on top of the weak convergence is a quite common technique in showing the convergence of moments.

First, I think the statement can be made a little more general (and slightly more rigorous) as follows (for an even more general statement which allows for $X_n$ is a sum of independent but non-identical Bernoulli random variables, refer to Theorem 23.2 in *Probability and Measure* (3rd edition) by Patrick Billingsley):

> *Suppose $X_n \sim \text{B}(n, p_n)$, where $p_n$ satisfies $p_n \to 0$ and $np_n \to a$ for some positive constant $a$, then for $r \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $E[X_n^r] \to E[X^r]$, where $X \sim \text{Poisson}(a)$.*

One way to exploit the already-known convergence in law fact (i.e., $X_n \Rightarrow X$) is to prove $\{X_n^r\}$ is uniformly integrable (U.I.).  Given that we can show $\{X_n^r\}$ is U.I., it then follows by $X_n^r \Rightarrow X^r$ (this is the consequence of continuous mapping theorem) that $E[X_n^r] \to E[X^r]$ (a formal theorem of this kind can be found in Theorem 25.12 in Billingsley's book as well).

To show that $\{X_n^r\}$ is U.I., it is sufficient to show $\sup_n E[X_n^{2r}] < \infty$. [Since](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Higher_moments)

\begin{align*}
E[X_n^{2r}] &= \sum_{k = 0}^{2r}\left\lbrace 2r\atop k \right\rbrace n(n - 1)\cdots(n - k + 1)p_n^k  \leq \sum_{k = 0}^{2r}\left\lbrace 2r\atop k \right\rbrace (np_n)^k, 
\end{align*}
it can be seen by the condition $np_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$ that $E[X_n^{2r}]$ can be bounded uniformly by a constant that is independent of $n$. Hence $\sup_n E[X_n^{2r}] < \infty$. This completes the proof.